# How to create a Setter/Getter of UserControl in VB6?

Tags: vb6, user-controls, oop

For an unknown reason, VB6 doesn't interact the same way with UserControl than other object.

I have a class that require to hold a graphical interface, a user control and need to be set to be later used from the get method. I have try many thing like using the special class VBControlExtender but without any success.

Here is what I have so far:

#### Class that hold variables and the user control:

```
'...
Private WithEvents m_uGUI As VBControlExtender

Public Property Get GUI() As VBControlExtender
    Set GUI = m_uGUI
End Property

Public Property Set GUI(ByVal uValue As VBControlExtender)
    Set m_uGUI = uValue
End Property
'...
```

#### Call of the class that cannot compile:

```
Set myObject.GUI = new ucMyUserControl
```

Any idea?

Comment: If I change VBControlExtender to UserControl, I still have the same error "invalid use of new KeyWord". Both doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the help on this error (it mentions ListBox and Form, but the same applies to UserControls):

> The New keyword can only be applied to
>   a creatable object...  You tried to
>   instantiate an Automation object, but
>   it was not a creatable object. For
>   example, you tried to create a new
>   instance of a list box by specifying
>   ListBox in a statement like the
>   following: [sample code snipped]
>   ListBox and Form are class names, not
>   specific object names. You can use
>   them to specify that a variable will
>   be a reference to a certain object
>   type...  But you can't use them to
>   instantiate the objects themselves in
>   a Set statement. You must specify a
>   specific object, rather than the
>   generic class name, in the Set
>   statement:

What you want to do is make an array of your UserControls and load new ones as you need them.  Set the Index property of your UserControl to 0 to make it an array and then use the Load statement to create new instances:

```
Load ucMyUserControl(1) 
Set myObject.GUI = ucMyUserControl(1)
```

When you need more just specify a new upper bound:

```
Load ucMyUserControl(2) 
Load ucMyUserControl(3)
...
```

When you're done with them, unload them:

```
Unload ucMyUserControl(3)
Unload ucMyUserControl(2)
...
```

Comment: +1. Ahhh, it's the New statement with a control type, of course it is. You can't do that in VB6. Nice answer.

Comment: I do not see how to make an array of UserControl in a Class and load them to a form when needed. I understand your point of view if I would have to load them directly in a form but I have to hold the usercontrol in a class until the desire moment is trigged.

Answer (score 0):

I believe VBControlExtender [can only be used with dynamically added controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa267210(VS.60).aspx) (i.e. Controls.Add) not intrinsic controls. Why can't you use `ucMyUserControl` as the type instead?

Comment: I cannot use ucMyUserControl because depending of the sentence in the program the user control will be set to ucMyUserControl1 and sometime to ucMyUserControl2. If I change VBControlExtender to UserControl, I still have the same error "invalid use of new KeyWord"